# Generic method that expands its return type

Tags: haskell

I have the data type for matrices defined as `Matrix a`. In most places in my program, I use it with either strings as `Matrix String` or with other matrices as `Matrix (Matrix a)`.

I need to write a function that pads the content of the matrix according to certain rules. For string matrices the signature would be:

```
pad :: Matrix String -> Matrix (Matrix String)
```

because each string is converted into a matrix of a certain size.

For matrices with other matrices in them, the function should be:

```
pad :: Matrix (Matrix a) -> Matrix (Matrix a)
```

because in this case only the size of the inner matrices is changing.

Is there a way to generalize those two? I tried this:

```
class Paddable b => Paddable a where
    pad :: a -> Matrix b
```

and then declaring `String` and `Matrix a` as `Paddable`, but this fails with an obvious "Could not deduce... from the context" error, which is expected as I don't define my `pad` function to cover all possible values of `b`.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that both versions of pad are doing conceptually different things, so they should probably have different names too. It's not always a good idea to define a type class when you've spotted some apparent pattern in your code.

That said... you can do as attempted with an [associated type family](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Associated_type_instances):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Paddable (PaddedContent a) => Paddable a where
  type PaddedContent a :: *
  pad :: Matrix a -> Matrix (PaddedContent a)

instance Paddable String where
  type PaddedContent String = Matrix String
  pad = ...

instance Paddable (Matrix a) where
  type PaddedContent (Matrix a) = Matrix a
  pad = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature is

```
pad :: Matrix a -> Matrix b
```

where `b` is determined by `a`. So, it can be done using [**functional dependencies**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances,
             MultiParamTypeClasses,
             FunctionalDependencies #-}

data Matrix a = Matrix a deriving Show

class Paddable a b | a -> b where
    pad :: Matrix a -> Matrix b

instance Paddable (Matrix a) (Matrix a) where
    pad = id  -- dummy implementation!

instance Paddable String (Matrix String) where
    pad (Matrix str) = Matrix . Matrix $ ">> " ++  str ++ " <<"
```

then:

```
\> pad $ Matrix (Matrix 42)
Matrix (Matrix 42)

\> pad $ Matrix "abc"
Matrix (Matrix ">> abc <<")
```